# Multiple Categorical Variables in a Column & The Prep

Tags: python, r, excel, pandas, statistics

I have a survey data, with text answers, categorical variables, and numeric.

Converted into a dataframe in pandas, but the problem is multiple-choice columns, sometimes have more than 1 categorical variables, because the survey was designed as "choose all applies".

For example:

```
ID  Category    Num1 Num2 Num3
1   A, B, C     1    1    1
2   B, C, D     1    0    1
3   A, C        1    1    1
4   A           0    1    1
5   A, C, D     0    1    1
```

I am trying to correlate these categories to the numerical variables.

Let's say the presence of A to value of Num1.

But when I use the dataframe, as it is, Python (and R) considers, for example [A, B, C] as another category, recognizes the whole cell as the category.

I think I need a method of parsing (exploding?) the value (in a hidden way), before feeding into a statistical analysis command.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have a similar question, and this one is not really a duplicate as the other is specific to R. I would love to see this solved in a generic way for python and pandas.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape` in `R`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(df1, "Category", type =  "character", fill = 0, sep=",\\s*", fixed = FALSE)
#   ID Category Num1 Num2 Num3 Category_A Category_B Category_C Category_D
#1  1  A, B, C    1    1    1          1          1          1          0
#2  2  B, C, D    1    0    1          0          1          1          1
#3  3     A, C    1    1    1          1          0          1          0
#4  4        A    0    1    1          1          0          0          0
#5  5  A, C, D    0    1    1          1          0          1          1
```

---

In `base R`, we can split the 'Category' column at `,` and then use `table`

```
cbind(df1, as.data.frame.matrix(table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df1$Category,
             ",\\s+"), df1$ID))[2:1])))
#   ID Category Num1 Num2 Num3 A B C D
#1  1  A, B, C    1    1    1 1 1 1 0
#2  2  B, C, D    1    0    1 0 1 1 1
#3  3     A, C    1    1    1 1 0 1 0
#4  4        A    0    1    1 1 0 0 0
#5  5  A, C, D    0    1    1 1 0 1 1
```

---

It can be made further compact with

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1, mtabulate(strsplit(df1$Category, ",\\s+")))
#  ID Category Num1 Num2 Num3 A B C D
#1  1  A, B, C    1    1    1 1 1 1 0
#2  2  B, C, D    1    0    1 0 1 1 1
#3  3     A, C    1    1    1 1 0 1 0
#4  4        A    0    1    1 1 0 0 0
#5  5  A, C, D    0    1    1 1 0 1 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Category = c("A, B, C", "B, C, D", "A, C", 
"A", "A, C, D"), Num1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Num2 = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Num3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is called `df`, then you can test for the presence of "A" in `Category` like this:

```
grepl("A", as.character(df$Category))
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you want TRUE and FALSE as 1 and 0 you just do:

```
grepl("A", as.character(df$Category)) * 1
#> [1] 1 0 1 1 1
```

If you want them all at once, do:

```
sapply(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), function(x) grepl(x, as.character(df$Category)) * 1)
#>      A B C D
#> [1,] 1 1 1 0
#> [2,] 0 1 1 1
#> [3,] 1 0 1 0
#> [4,] 1 0 0 0
#> [5,] 1 0 1 1
```

Or if you want them as columns in your original data frame, do:

```
cbind(df, sapply(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), function(x) grepl(x, as.character(df$Category)) * 1))
#>   ID Category Num1 Num2 Num3 A B C D
#> 1  1  A, B, C    1    1    1 1 1 1 0
#> 2  2  B, C, D    1    0    1 0 1 1 1
#> 3  3     A, C    1    1    1 1 0 1 0
#> 4  4        A    0    1    1 1 0 0 0
#> 5  5  A, C, D    0    1    1 1 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use `tidyverse` (or `tidyr` plus `dplyr`), I think you could use `separate_rows`. This will split up your categories, and then you can use `pivot_wider` to make additional columns for these categories.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  separate_rows(Category, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(temp = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Category, values_from = temp, values_fill = list(temp = FALSE))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 8
     ID  Num1  Num2  Num3 A     B     C     D    
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1     1     1     1     1 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
2     2     1     0     1 FALSE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
3     3     1     1     1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE
4     4     0     1     1 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
5     5     0     1     1 TRUE  FALSE TRUE  TRUE
```